# Convert html tags to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

I have a system status page from a partner that I am trying to convert so that I can automate its input into my service page. The status of the service is provided by a `<span>` class. I know this is far from ideal but this is the only way that they provide updates.

Below is a copy of the HTML:

```
<ul class="item-3">
    <li class="status service1">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <h6>
        SERVICE 1
        </h6>
        <p>
        Updated:
        9:52 AM CST Apr, 24
        </p>
        <span class="arrow up"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="status service2">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <h6>
        SERVICE 2
        </h6>
        <p>
        Updated:
        9:52 AM CST Apr, 24
        </p>
        <span class="arrow up"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="status service3">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <h6>
        SERVICE 3
        </h6>
        <p>
        Updated:
        9:52 AM CST Apr, 24
        </p>
        <span class="arrow up"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to grab the `<span class="arrow up">` values as this is the service status, and the `<li class="status service3">` as this tells me what service it is.

Since my status page API uses IDs and not "up/down" etc I will need the statuses and services to be in arrays so I can convert them into my formats - hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Use `loadHTML` method

```
<?php
   $str = '<h1>T1</h1>Lorem ipsum.<h1>T2</h1>The quick red fox...<h1>T3</h1>... jumps over the lazy brown FROG';
   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($str);

   //get all H1
   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h1');

   //display all H1 text
   for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
?>
```

Output:

```
 T1
 T2
 T3
```

Comment: Thanks @Vector but I need to load this from an existing .html file not. Also, the solution you give outputs the content of the tags where i need to ouput the class of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely certain what you are trying to achieve, but I'll make a few assumptions to clarify what I say:

I assume you don't generate the HTML yourself, but that you want to grab certain elements from the HTML you present in your question, thereby making it impossible to assign the full HTML to a variable.

The two possible **classes** in the span would either be *"arrow up"* or *"arrow down"* (as a matter of fact that's two classes, namely *"arrow"* and *"up"* (or "down"). So if for intstance you want to grab all instances of these span elements, you could simply do the following:

```
$ElementsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow");
```

This will give you an array of all elements of the class "arrow" no matter if they also contain the class "up" or the class "down". If you want to be able to only select all "up" or "down" you could do the same just like this:

```
$arrayOfUps = document.getElementsByClassName("up");
```

Assuming there are more elements containing the class **"up"** (such as *"elevator up"*, *"seven up"*, etc.) you can also use the same function to search for elements containing *both* class names like this:

```
$arrayOfUps = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow up");
```

That way you make sure you don't also get the elements containing:

*class="seven up", class="elevator up", etc.*

If you only want to get an array of all instances of arrow (either "up" or "down") and iterate through each instance, you can of course do the following:

```
$searchFor = "arrow";
$results = array();
$arrCounter=0;
var $elementsList= document.getElementsByClassName("arrow");
for ($i=0; i < $elementsList->length; i++) {
   $temp = $elementsList->item($i);
   if (stripos($temp->getAttribute('class'), $searchFor) !== false) {
       $results[$arrCounter] = ( stripos($temp->getAttribute('class'), "up") !== false ) ? "UP" : "DOWN" ;
       $arrCounter++;
   }
}
```

The same goes for the list-items.

This i by no means elegant coding, and I would also turn this into a function, but I only wanted to suggest the PHP DOM functions to use for the purpose you suggested.

English is not my first language, so I might have completely missed your point, and in that case I apologize in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! Yes you are correct, I do not generate the html page, this is done via the provider and I grab this via wget every X mins). I have never used PHP DOM before, would you be able to show how i would set this up to load this from the HTML file i get?

Comment: @RedSpider


The simplest would be to use this PHP Simple DOM Parser:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/



_That will make it possible to use code such as:_

`$html = file_get_html('http://www.myhtml.com/');`

Comment: @RedSpider

If the HTML document you want to scan through is on the same domain as your script, you can also load it into an **iframe** and use the **innerHTML** of the **iframe**. But the security prevents using innerHTML on iframes containing html from another domain. So the safest way to go would probably be the DOM parser mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. I am still a bit confused (sorry!). I tried to copy the code you posted but i get an `unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)`